# HTML Input type image being cut off in Chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have setup some voting buttons using an input element set as an image, to display an icon.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="bottomBarControls">

<form id="voteDownForm" action="index.php?ajax=vote" method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="castVote">

  <input type="hidden" name="clippetID" value="@clippetID">

  <input type="hidden" name="downvote">

  <input id="voteDownButton" type="image" src="images/icons/@downvoteStatus.png" alt="downvote" name="downvote" value="Downvote">

</form>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#voteUpForm, #voteDownForm
{
  display: inline-block;
}

#voteUpButton, #voteDownButton
{
  height: 32px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 7px;
  display: block;
}

#bottomBarControls
{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#voteCounter
{
  display: inline-block;
}

#views
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

As you can see the up and down buttons are getting cut off on the bottom and right, this only happens in Chrome, I tested it in edge and firefox and it displays fine. It also does the same thing with a normal img tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the icon natively by making them 32 x 32 and not using CSS to scale them down, everything is ok after that.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default styles. If you don't set every single attribute, differences can creep in.

To address this, many web decks use a [CSS reset script](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) and lay down their styles on top of it.